# Routing IPsec VPN for VM subnet

Tags: vpn, routing, virt-manager, strongswan

My physical computer is able to establish an IPsec tunnel (with Strongswan) to my internet-accessible VPS, so that my physical computer's internet traffic goes through my VPS.

I also tried and was successful in setting up Strongswan in a VM running on my physical machine. Expectedly, my VM can access the internet through my VPS.

What I'd like to do is have Strongswan running on my physical computer, so that the traffic of all my VM's (in 192.168.122.0/24) goes through my VPS. I think this should be do-able with a site-to-site configuration (example here:https://www.strongswan.org/testing/testresults/ikev2/net2net-cert/), however I haven't been able to get it to work. I'm not sure if my problem is with the Strongswan configuration, or with my VM networking configuration, or both...

ipsec.conf on my physical machine:

```
config setup
    charondebug="ike 2, cfg 2"

conn kvm-test
    rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes256gcm128-sha512-modp8192!
    esp=aes256gcm128-sha512-modp8192!
    leftcert=client.pem
    auto=add
    right=123.123.123.123 # not my VPS's actual IP
    rightcert=vpn_server.pem
    leftsubnet=192.168.122.0/24
    left=192.168.1.2
```

ipsec.conf on my VPS:

```
config setup
        # strictcrlpolicy=yes
        # uniqueids = no

conn %default
    keyexchange=ikev2
    leftfirewall=yes
    auto=add
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    left=123.123.123.123 # not my VPS's actual IP
    ike=aes256gcm128-sha512-modp8192!
    esp=aes256gcm128-sha512-modp8192!

conn kvm-test
    leftcert=vpn_server.pem
    rightcert=client.pem
    rightsubnet=192.168.122.0/24
```

With this configuration, the connection is successfully established, however my VM's traffic does not go through it. I should note that `ip route show table 220` does not show anything, which is unlike the example linked to above, and I'm not sure what I should put there... `ip route add table 220 default via 123.123.123.123 proto static` doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your virtualization solution NAT the traffic from 192.168.122.0/24 to your hosts physical IP (192.168.1.2)? If so, you have to avoid that and add a rule that accepts traffic that matches an IPsec policy (see [here](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling#Hosts-on-the-Internet)).

Comment: ecdsa, many thanks - that worked! please submit your comment as an answer, and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your virtualization solution NATs the traffic from 192.168.122.0/24 to your host's physical IP (192.168.1.2) you need to avoid that and add a rule that accepts traffic that matches an IPsec policy.
For instance ([more details](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/ForwardingAndSplitTunneling#Hosts-on-the-Internet)):

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -o eth0 -m policy --dir out --pol ipsec -j ACCEPT
```